# Find minimal path through a maze via check points

Tags: java, matrix, maze

I'm trying to find minimal path from starting point 'S' to goal 'G' through all check points'@'.
Although i heard Best First Search is efficient,I used Breadth First Search using a queue.
I'm creating new Mazestate object for each possible path from every point and adding it to queue.
But when i alter the value at a position in one object of queue,its value is changed in all other objects also(Atleast that is what i'm thinking is happening).

Please tell me where i'm going wrong.
I think there is something wrong with 'maze1' or 'temp.maze2'

Sorry for shabby code.

```
class ortry1
{
    static int w,h;
    static int sx,sy,gx,gy;
    static int anos=0;
    public static char[][] maze3=null;
    static boolean goalfound=false;
    static Queue<Mazestate> statequeue=new LinkedList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        w=(int)scan.nextInt();
        h=(int)scan.nextInt();
        maze3=new char[h][w];
        String tempo=null;
        for(int i=0;i<h;i++)
        {
            tempo=br.readLine();
            maze3[i]=tempo.toCharArray();
            if(tempo.indexOf('S')!=-1)
            {
                sx=i;sy=tempo.indexOf('S');
            }
            if(tempo.indexOf('G')!=-1)
            {
                gx=i;gy=tempo.indexOf('G');
            }           
                for(int k=0;k<w;k++)
                {
                    if(maze3[i][k]=='@')
                    {
                        anos++;
                    }
                }
        }

    statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze3,sx, sy, 0, 0));
    ortry1 o=new ortry1();
    while(!goalfound)
    {
        o.populatequeue();
    }

    }
private void populatequeue() 
{
    if (statequeue.peek()!=null)
    {
        Mazestate temp=statequeue.poll();
        char[][] maze1=temp.maze2.clone();
        int curx=temp.curx;
        int cury=temp.cury;
        int atscrossed=temp.atscrossed;
        int stepcount=temp.stepcount;
        System.out.println(atscrossed+"    "+stepcount);

        if(maze1[curx][cury]=='.'){maze1[curx][cury]='1';}
        else if(maze1[curx][cury]=='1'){maze1[curx][cury]='2';}
        else if(maze1[curx][cury]=='2'){maze1[curx][cury]='3';}
        else if(maze1[curx][cury]=='3'){maze1[curx][cury]='4';}
        else if(maze1[curx][cury]=='@'){maze1[curx][cury]='1';}
        else if(maze1[curx][cury]=='S'){maze1[curx][cury]='1';}



        for(int y=0;y<h;y++){System.out.println();
        for(int z=0;z<w;z++)
        {System.out.print(maze1[y][z]+"   ");}}


        //------------UP[curx-1][cury]--------------

        if(((curx-1)>=0)&&(maze1[curx-1][cury]!='#')&&(maze1[curx-1][cury]!='4'))
        {
            System.out.print("up        ");
            if((maze1[curx-1][cury]=='G'))
            {
                System.out.println("inG");
                if(atscrossed==ortry1.anos)
                {
                    goalfound=true;
                    System.out.println("===="+(stepcount+1));
                }else
                {
                    statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx-1, cury, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
                }
            }else if(maze1[curx-1][cury]=='@')
            {
                System.out.print("in@");            
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx-1, cury, atscrossed+1, stepcount+1));
            }else if(maze1[curx-1][cury]=='.')
            {
                System.out.println("in.");          
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx-1, cury, atscrossed, stepcount+1));

            }else if(maze1[curx-1][cury]=='1')
            {
                System.out.println("in1");              
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx-1, cury, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }else if(maze1[curx-1][cury]=='2')
            {
                System.out.println("in2");              
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx-1, cury, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }else if(maze1[curx-1][cury]=='3')
            {
                System.out.println("in3");
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx-1, cury, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }
            maze1=temp.maze2.clone();
        }
        //-----------DOWN[curx+1][cury]------------
        if(((curx+1)<ortry1.h)&&(maze1[curx+1][cury]!='#')&&(maze1[curx+1][cury]!='4'))
        {
            System.out.print("down      ");
            if((maze1[curx+1][cury]=='G'))
            {
                System.out.println("inG");
                if(atscrossed==ortry1.anos)
                {
                    goalfound=true;
                    System.out.println("===="+(stepcount+1));
                }else
                {
                    statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx+1, cury, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
                }
            }else   if(maze1[curx+1][cury]=='@')
            {
                System.out.println("in@");  
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx+1, cury, atscrossed+1, stepcount+1));
            }else if(maze1[curx+1][cury]=='.')
            {
                System.out.println("in.");  
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx+1, cury, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }

            else if(maze1[curx+1][cury]=='1')
            {
                System.out.println("in1");  
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx+1, cury, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }else if(maze1[curx+1][cury]=='2')
            {
                System.out.println("in2");
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx+1, cury, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }else if(maze1[curx+1][cury]=='3')
            {
                System.out.println("in3");
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx+1, cury, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }

        maze1=temp.maze2.clone();
        }

        //------------LEFT[curx][cury-1]-----------------
        if(((cury-1)>=0)&&(maze1[curx][cury-1]!='#')&&(maze1[curx][cury-1]!='4'))
        {
            System.out.print("left      ");
             if((maze1[curx][cury-1]=='G'))
            {
                System.out.println("inG");
                if(atscrossed==ortry1.anos)
                {
                    goalfound=true;
                    System.out.println("===="+(stepcount+1));
                }else
                {
                    statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx, cury-1, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
                }
            }else   if(maze1[curx][cury-1]=='@')
            {
                System.out.println("in@");
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx, cury-1, atscrossed+1, stepcount+1));
            }else if(maze1[curx][cury-1]=='.')
            {
                System.out.println("in.");
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx, cury-1, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }
            else if(maze1[curx][cury-1]=='1')
            {
                System.out.println("in1");
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx, cury-1, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }else if(maze1[curx][cury-1]=='2')
            {
                System.out.println("in2");
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx, cury-1, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }else if(maze1[curx][cury-1]=='3')
            {
                System.out.println("in3");
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx, cury-1, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }



        maze1=temp.maze2.clone();
        }
        //------------RIGHT[curx][cury+1]---------------
        if(((cury+1)<ortry1.w)&&(maze1[curx][cury+1]!='#')&&(maze1[curx][cury+1]!='4'))
        {
            System.out.print("right     ");
             if((maze1[curx][cury+1]=='G'))
            {
                System.out.println("inG");
                if(atscrossed==ortry1.anos)
                {
                    goalfound=true;
                    System.out.println("===="+(stepcount+1));
                }else
                {
                    statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx, cury+1, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
                }
            }else   if(maze1[curx][cury+1]=='@')
            {
                System.out.println("in@");
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx, cury+1, atscrossed+1,     stepcount+1));                       
            }else if(maze1[curx][cury+1]=='.')
            {
                System.out.println("in.");
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx, cury+1, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }

            else if(maze1[curx][cury+1]=='1')
            {
                System.out.println("in1");
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx, cury+1, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }else if(maze1[curx][cury+1]=='2')
            {
                System.out.println("in2");
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx, cury+1, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }else if(maze1[curx][cury+1]=='3')
            {
                System.out.println("in3");
                statequeue.add(new Mazestate(maze1,curx, cury+1, atscrossed, stepcount+1));
            }

            maze1=temp.maze2.clone();

        }   
        for(int y=0;y<h;y++){System.out.println();
        for(int z=0;z<w;z++)
        {System.out.print(maze1[y][z]+"   ");}}

    }

}
```

}

```
class Mazestate
{
    char[][] maze2=null;
    int curx,cury;//current position
    int atscrossed;//no. of @ crossed
    int stepcount;//no. of steps taken;
    public Mazestate(char[][] maze1,int curx,int cury,int atscrossed,int stepcount) 
    {
        this.maze2=maze1.clone();
        this.curx=curx;
        this.cury=cury;
        this.atscrossed=atscrossed;
        this.stepcount=stepcount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is at `char[][] maze1=temp.maze2;`, at the beggining of the method `populatequeue()`.

Both maze1 and temp.maze2 now point to the **same object** (you are duplicating the reference,not the object), so when you modify maze1 or temp.maze2 you are changing the same object.

If you want to create two different objects you can use the method **clone()**.

> char[][] maze1 = temp.maze2.clone();

Comment: I'm having same problem even after cloning 'maze2'. I even tried to clone "maze1" in Mazestate's constructor     this.maze2=maze1.clone();       Still having same problem.

Comment: @KarthickVinod When you make a `statequeue.add` and then you modify again `maze1` you are also **updating the object you added to the queque**, since you added the **same reference** each time. This happens to you if on the same call to `populatequeque()` there are **more than one** path available. You modify `maze1` after it was added to the queque before.

Comment: I got what you said. To solve that issue i added `maze1=temp.maze2.clone();` after adding each element to `statequeue`.So now  i think i'm not adding same reference to queue.But still im having same problem.Sorry for asking repeated questions.